# Whitespace between HTML input and button

Tags: html, css

I wanted a button next to my input box so I did the following.

```
<div>
    <input/>
    <button>Do something</button>
</div>
```

This gave a small gap between the input and the button.

To my surprise this didn't

```
<div>
    <input/><button>Do something</button>
</div>
```

My question is:

I assume the gap is deliberate and represents the white space for my newline.  Is this assumption correct and is there some good practise for avoiding the problem?  Can I style out the gap, or should I just stick to putting the tags on the same line?

I've tried to represent my question here http://jsfiddle.net/jonnymoo/2wzdzfan/5/

```
<div>
    <input value="look no gap between me"/><button>and me</button>
</div>
<div>
    <input value="But there is here"/>
    <button>and here</button>
</div>
<div>
    Is it just the same as me
    and me?
</div>
```

Comment: Ah ha - yes it is the same question as noted by Vucko and Paulie_D, just with different html tags!  Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `font-size:0;` to the surrounding `div` like this:

```css
.no-gap {
  font-size:0;  
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input value="look no gap between me"/><button>and me</button>
</div>
<div class="no-gap">
    <input value="But there is here"/>
    <button>and here</button>
</div>
<div>
    Is it just the same as me
    and me?
</div>
```